# Prepare dependency property for invalid value

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have created `UserControl` that provides few `dependency properties`. The value of one of them is `int`. Now the user has provided the `null` as value and an exception has been thrown:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='<null>'` ...

Which is a valid behaviour (by WPF I believe?). However I want to prepare my `UserControl` for such incident. I mean, if binding provides invalid value I want to catch this and provide my default value, so no exceptin is thrown.

How to achieve this? I've tried with `DependencyPropertyChangedCallback`, `CoerceValueCallback` and `ValidateValueCallback` callbacks but it seems none of them receive this value.

Comment: Your UserControl can't react on this because the error arises in the Binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set an `int` property to anything else than an `int` value so your dependency property in the `UserControl` is actually never being called and there is nothing that the `UserControl` can do about this as the property never gets set.

It is the responsibility of the consumer of any class including a `UserControl` to be able to set a property to a value of the property type.

In this case the error occurs when when the WPF runtime is trying to set your `int` property to a value that doesn't represent a valid integer, such as for example `null`.

What you could do is to use a `ValidationRule` to do something before the value conversion occurs and present an error message to the user if the conversion fails:

[How do I handle DependencyProperty overflow situations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549918/how-do-i-handle-dependencyproperty-overflow-situations/41552712#41552712)

Another option may be to change the type of the dependency property to `Nullable<int>` (`int?`). Then you will be able to set it to any valid integer value as well as `null`.

Answer (score 0):

In your binding where you bind to that DependencyProperty u can set NullValue and FallbackValue.
Somethinkg like.

```
 <TextBlock  Text="{Binding SomeProperty, FallbackValue='Null not suported', TargetNullValue={x:Null}}"/>
```