# Disable and handle 'Value could not be converted' validation error on WPF textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding

I want to be able to override the default textbox validation for convertion and handle it myself. I've looked at validation rules but I can't get it to disable the original validation. Xaml so far:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Option.Value, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SourceUpdated">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OptionValueChanged}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
       </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Atm, when a string is entered it displays 'Value {val} cannot be converted' as the field is an integer. How can this be disabled to handle the value myself?

Comment: If you want to handle the conversion between a string and an int yourself you could use a converter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `int` property can only be set to an `int` value and nothing else. You could customize the error message but you won't ever be able to set the `int` property to something else than an `int`.

Please refer to the answer here for an example of how to use a custom `ValidationRule` to customize the error message:

[How do I handle DependencyProperty overflow situations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549918/how-do-i-handle-dependencyproperty-overflow-situations/41552712#41552712)

If you want to handle the actual conversion between the `string` and the `int` yourself you could use a converter:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:YourConverter x:Key="conv" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Option.Value, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Coverter={StaticResource conv}}" / >
```

---

```
public class YourConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //convert the int to a string:
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //convert the string back to an int here
        return int.Parse(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't want to convert it to a string but if the user was to specify a value that was not an int  it would default to say 0 and I would be able to handle the message myself

Comment: Use a custom validation rule as per the link then.

Comment: Will do, I'm just trying it out now

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and adding `TargetNullValue=''` didn't work. Adding a converter like the accepted answer here suggests didn't work ither. However, in my case, the issue was with a `ContactId` and when the Customers ComboBox was changed it populated the Contacts. When the Contacts `ObserveableCollection<Contact>.Clear()` was called it was throwing this error.

My fix was to ensure that the `ContactId` had changed before `ObserveableCollection<Contact>.Clear()` and `ObserveableCollection<Contact>.Add(contact)` was called.